# Is there a way to make the share menu suggestions more useful?

Tags: android-12

For instance: wanted to share a reddit link. So I hit the share button in Relay (reddit client). The first four suggestions:

1. Signal, a friend that I just texted a few minutes ago
2. Telegram, my kid
3. Telegram, a person I've texted exactly once and it was 2 months ago
4. Telegram, a person who I've texted 4 or 5 times but haven't used Telegram to message them in 5 months

Meanwhile there's a person I message on Telegram about 20 times a day and they are not in the suggestion list.

Same results sharing from Spotify so I think it's a system menu, not an app-specific menu.

Is there some way to reset these suggestions? They seem worthless/broken. It was the same way in Android 11. Surely there's some system process that's updating these values.